# How do I get all the files inside a picture library in sharepoint 2010 using c# clientside code(CSOM)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a picture library in SharePoint 2010 site in which I am have 3 folders A, B, and C.
If I want to retrieve data from Folder A, how would I do it in SharePoint 2010 using c# code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code:

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(url))
    {

        var srcList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
        var qry = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
        qry.FolderServerRelativeUrl = string.Format("/{0}",srcFolder);
        var srcItems = srcList.GetItems(qry);
        context.Load(srcItems, icol => icol.Include
            (i => i.FileSystemObjectType,
                i => i.File));
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (var item in srcItems)
        {
            if (item.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.File)
            {
                item.File; // Here you can get the file object,
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the above code what does Filesystemobjecttype indicates.
Is it related to specific file extensions or ...

Comment: No, It checks if item is file or folder.

Comment: If you dont mind can you explain the code using a simple example as i have said my problem above..

Answer (score 1):

Use [CamlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.folderserverrelativeurl.aspx) to restrict a  folder from which results will be returned. 
The following example demonstrates how to retrieve list items located under `Orders` folder in `Documents` library:

```
var listTitle = "Documents";
var folderName = "Orders";

var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
context.Load(list.RootFolder);
context.ExecuteQuery();

var qry = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
qry.FolderServerRelativeUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, folderName);
var items = list.GetItems(qry);
context.Load(items);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```